# restar valores de 2 variables

Tags: actionscript

Como puedo restar los valores obtenidos al presionar estos 2 botones?, es decir, restar el "inicio" al "fin" y obtener los milisegundos.

```
var inicio:int;
var fin:int;
var milisec1:int;
var milisec2:int;

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click1);
function click1(e:MouseEvent):void{
  var milisec1:Date = new Date();
  var inicio = milisec1.getTime();
  salida1.text = inicio;
}

btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click2);
function click2(e:MouseEvent):void{
  var milisec2:Date = new Date();
  var fin = milisec2.getTime();
  salida2.text = fin;
}
```

Comment: `total=inicio-fin;`
creo que tienes que quitar el var que pones dentro de las funciones para que el scope no te lo tome como una nueva variable.

Comment: En Actionscript 2 eso sería sencillo, pero en AS3 me arroja como 6 errores

Comment: cuales son esos 6 errores? si cuando defines milisec1 y milisec2 usas date en lugar de int?

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema con el Scope,  al declarar dos veces tus variable una queda como variable Global y la otra como Local dentro de la  función, así que cuando le asignas un valor a milisec1 solo es accesible desde la función click1, por lo cual cuando lo intentas restarlo te marcaría que milisec1 es NULL

```
var startTime: Date;
var endTime: Date;

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click1);

function click1(e: MouseEvent): void {
 startTime = new Date();
 var inicio = startTime.getTime();
 salida1.text = inicio;
}

btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click2);

function click2(e: MouseEvent): void {
 endTime = new Date();
 var fin = endTime.getTime();     
 salida2.text = fin;
 var total:int = Math.floor(endTime.valueOf() - startTime.valueOf());
 trace(total);
}
```

Comment: El código que publiqué es todo el código que estoy usando (probando), tu código me arroja 5 errores...
Hasta el minuto puedo obtener los mili segundos de pinchar el 1er botón y los mili segundos de pinchar el 2do botón, pero no sé como restar el 1ro al 2do, para obtener los mili segundos entre los 2 clicks

Comment: si compartes los errores seria mas fácil ayudarte a depurarlo

Comment: 1067: Conversión implícita de un valor de tipo Date a un tipo Class no relacionado.


1188: Asignación no válida a la clase Date.


1067: Conversión implícita de un valor de tipo Date a un tipo Class no relacionado.


1188: Asignación no válida a la clase Date.


1120: Acceso a una propiedad salida3 no definida.

Comment: **Error** Escena 1, Capa 'Capa 1', Fotograma 1, Línea 36: 1067: Conversión implícita de un valor de tipo Date a un tipo Class no relacionado.
     startTime: Date = new Date();

Comment: **Error** Escena 1, Capa 'Capa 1', Fotograma 1, Línea 36: 1188: Asignación no válida a la clase Date.
     startTime: Date = new Date();

Comment: **Error** Escena 1, Capa 'Capa 1', Fotograma 1, Línea 44: 1067: Conversión implícita de un valor de tipo Date a un tipo Class no relacionado.
     endTime: Date = new Date();

Comment: **Error** Escena 1, Capa 'Capa 1', Fotograma 1, Línea 44: 1188: Asignación no válida a la clase Date.
     endTime: Date = new Date();

Comment: **Error** Escena 1, Capa 'Capa 1', Fotograma 1, Línea 48: 1120: Acceso a una propiedad salida3 no definida.
     salida3.text = total;

Comment: @Lalo ya modifique el codigo, siguen apareciendo errores?

Comment: Ahí sí me funciona sin ningún problema, voy a dejar el código antiguo y el nuevo para observarlos... muchas gracias, te debo una cerveza, en serio jeje